# ContextMenu doesn't work with WPF inside WinForms when scale is not 100%

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, contextmenu, scaling

[image: ContextMenu Bug]

The bug happens when following conditions occur:

- The startup project is a WinForms application
- The WinForms application contains a WPF UserControl

  `private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ctrlHost = new ElementHost();
       ctrlHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       ctrlHost.AutoSize = true;
       panel1.Controls.Add(ctrlHost);
       wpfAddressCtrl = new Test.UserControl1();
       ctrlHost.Child = wpfAddressCtrl;
   }`
- The WPF UserControl uses a control with a ContextMenu (e.g. a button)
- The windows scaling on the monitor is more than 100% (e.g. 125%)
- The app.manifest in the WinForms application has this configuration

  `<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAware>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">permonitorv2,permonitor</dpiAwareness>
        <gdiScaling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">true</gdiScaling>
      </windowsSettings>
    </application>`

The only solution I found is to completely remove the 3 configs from the app.manifest (dpiAware, dpiAwareness and gdiScaling) but I want to know if there is any other way to fix this?

Here is my sample project with the bug:
https://gofile.io/?c=MwtPjb

**Edit:**
I found a very easy solution that worked for me and didn't require to change a huge application

I removed the gdiScaling and changed the other two to:

`<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
    <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">unaware</dpiAwareness>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>`

Comment: Remove this line: `<gdiScaling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">true</gdiScaling>`. It'll also, most probably, cause the virtualization of the hosting Forms.

Comment: @Jimi that would work to, but than I get some display bugs with many other things in my big application. (e.g. only half splashscreen is displayed, some icons become to big and others to small, etc.)

Comment: I know. You have to take care of your graphics objects. When you draw an Image, the DPI scaling of the Bitmap is taken into consideration now. You need to use resources with uniform definitions. Use an Image editor to change the DPI of all the Images to a single value for all (96dpi is OK). Use a single method to draw all the images, when not assigned to control that can scale them (a PictureBox with `SizeMode = Zoom`, for example). Anyway, this is something you can fix, with some work. Other *bugs*, as the one you're reporting, cannot be fixed adding a line in some configuration file.